# ubuntu, extract duplicate value from 2 files

Tags: file, ubuntu, duplicates, unique

how to extract duplicate and unique values from 2 files in ubuntu and save them in separate files
for example

file1.txt

```
abc
123
321
```

file2.txt

```
abc
123
321
456
```

how to extract duplicate and uniques?

output for duplicates between 2 files

duplicates.txt

```
abc
123
321
```

output for unique values between 2 files

unique.txt

```
456
```

I tried this
`awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}$1 in a' file1.txt RS="" file2.txt`

but did not get only duplicate and uniques, but I got all values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I have found solutions

to get duplicates

```
sort *.txt | awk '{print $1}' | uniq -d
```

to get unique, not correspondiong values

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$0]++; next} !($0 in a)' file1.txt file2.txt
or 
sort *.txt | awk '{print $1}' | uniq -u
```